# Not able to write complete data into firebase database when use finish method in onComplete

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I am using below code to add `postingdata` into firebase. The issue is, when I comment the `finish` method in `onComplete`, then all my data is correctly write in firebase database. But when I uncomment the `finish` method, most of the data is not written in datbase. I want to write full data with `finish` method.

```
mUserRefrence.child(user.getUid()).setValue(postingdata).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
        hideProgressDialog();
        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, e.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
        hideProgressDialog();
        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, getString(R.string.login_success), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
        finish();
    }
});
```

Comment: What do you mean "most of the data"? Can you show us the database structure and explain what is written and what is not written?

Comment: I am sending the data {email=t@t.com, name=david ,photoUrl=https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHOLT.png}
when i comment the finish above data is displayed correctlty when i uncomment the finish function
only email is written in the database

Comment: @Frank please solve my issue

Answer (score 0):

this happens because your are starting  new activity before firebase completing your current task to store user data on firebase databse.  you are calling finsh(); which will stops executing current task and will move to new Activity. what you can do is check if task in successful or not and then open new activity in your case main Activity . do it like this it might help you -

```
   }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
@Override
public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
     if (!task.issuccessful()) {

    // this piece of code will execute if task is Unsuccessful

     hideProgressDialog();
    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, getString(R.string.login_Unsuccess),   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     } 
   else {
      // this piece of cade will execute if task is successful

       hideProgressDialog();
       startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
       finish();
    } 


    }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with Firebase Database Rules Simulator. Please see the  status link: https://status.firebase.google.com/incident/Console/17012, Now it is showing resolved.